# Git push a different branch to github

Tags: git, github

I have a local master branch, after trying some stuff, decided to go back to commit X, like 4 previous commits, then I make a new branch "master2" and this is now my main branch.
When I try to do a new push (to my github) for my different branch it throws an error.

```
 git push -u origin master2
 ! [rejected]        master2 -> master2 (non-fast-forward)
```

How can i do a push to github for this new branch?

Comment: What's the current situation on Github? Does the branch exist? At what commit is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem completely, however, non-fast-forward pushes (which is your case) can be solved by adding `-f` switch (force) to the push command:

```
git push -fu origin master2
```

(however, using force push on e.g. Github is considered as a bad thing to do and there is a reason for that: you can mess up someone else repository, so you should do it only if you are sure that no one fetched the repository with the `master2` branch pointing to whatever it was before forcepush)

Comment: However, you probably shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The "non-fast-forward" error tells you that the `master2` branch already exists in your GitHub repo. I suggest that you check what commits are on this branch. You have two options:

1. Merge the GitHub version of `master2` with your local one:

   ```
   git pull origin master2
   ```

   If this runs without any conflicts, then you can simply push:

   ```
   git push origin master2
   ```

   If there were conflicts with the first command, then you need to resolve the conflicts and commit the changes:

   ```
   git commit
   ```

   Then you can push as before.
2. You can also just overwrite the existing `master2` branch:

   git push -f origin master2

   **Warning:** Be very careful about doing this, though, as it will cause headaches for anyone who has already pulled the `master2` branch and merged or commited to it.